# Is there any possible to create apk file run on my android device without adobe air in flash cs6 tecnology?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, flash-cs6, android-2.2-froyo

I am Developing my first game in flash professional cs6 and as3,when i publish a apk file it need  adobe air runtime to run on my android device. i need my game to run on android device which is not install adobe air. Is there any possible to create apk file which is run on my android device without air run time in flash cs6 technology.

Thanks

Comment: Try to follow these instructions: http://permadi.com/blog/2012/03/publishing-apk-with-air-captive-runtime-with-flash-ide/

Comment: No it's not possible even when packaging with captive runtime some a the newest android device still require air captive runtime to be installed.

Comment: @BotMaster Can you please provide a source for that? It shouldn't matter what device the app is installed on with captive runtime, so long as Adobe AIR supports it. The captive runtime is compiled as part of the app itself. If you do this, it never even checks to see if Adobe AIR is installed on device since the runtime is already present in the app. As far as I am aware, your entire comment is false.

Comment: see the adobe website its help full   http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/concept-air-captive-runtime.html)